# Form.closed event is not firing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, event-handling

Whenever I click on form's red cross close button I want to display another form, but despite of having closed event handler, I'm unable to open another form.

This is how I'm trying to open another form:

```
private void Form1_Closed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     itemMaster.Show();

}
```

Could anyone please tell me how can I enable my requirment?

Answer (score 6):

First, you should use the [`FormClosed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed%28VS.90%29.aspx) event instead of `Closed`:

> *The `Closed` event is obsolete in the .NET Framework version 2.0; use the `FormClosed` event instead.* — [MSDN page for the `Form.Closed` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed.aspx)

```
void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Second, make sure that you have actually subscribed to `Form1`'s `FormClosed` event:

```
Form1.FormClosed += Form1_FormClosed;
```

The Windows Forms designer should've automatically added a similar line somewhere in `InitializeComponent`. If not, that's why your handler method doesn't get called.

If this still doesn't help, try handling the [`FormClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28VS.90%29.aspx) event insteaf of `FormClosed`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have started your application with the following statement:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

When you close `Form1`, your application will exit. Even if you open another form, it will be killed when application quits. Can you make sure this is the case by putting a breakpoint in your `Form1_Closed` method and see that the breakpoint is hit?

If this is the case, what happens is your code does execute but since the application quits, your another form also closes as soon as it opens.

To fix that, `Hide()` form1 instead of closing it. Handle `Form_Closing` event and call `this.Hide()` and set `e.Cancel = true`.

Answer (score 1):

When you're done with your form and you want to close it(by clicking on a close button for example), be sure to use `Close()`. My `form_closing` event didn't fired because I used only `Dispose()` when clicking the close button.

I think the best way to close a form is to use both `Close()` and `Dispose()`.

- `Close()` => if you need to do something when closing the form...
- `Dispose()` => to destroy the form (cleanup resources).

  private void _btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Close();
      Dispose();
  }